# An error may have occurred as part of the login process

Tags: facebook, authentication, symfony

Alright so I'm using symfony2 and using the symfony2 facebookbundle.
Whenever I login to facebook, only if I'm not already logged in, I get this error when I attempt to login to my application.

"An error may have occurred as part of the login process. You can close this window and try returning to the application, though it may ask you to login again. This is likely due to a bug in the application."

If I'm already logged into facebook, and click the button, it'll popup a window, close, and redirect to symfony's internal login process and bam, the user is logged in.

This is the code I use to initalize facebook

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({"appId":"myappidishere","xfbml":true,"oauth":true,"status":true,"cookie":true,"logging":true});
  onFbInit();
};

(function() {
  var e = document.createElement('script');
  e.src = document.location.protocol + "\/\/connect.facebook.net\/en_US\/all.js";
  e.async = true;
  document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
</script>
```

In the facebook app configuration I have my

NOTE: Where I'm logging in from is actually http://mysite.com.au/events/login

**App domains**: www.mysite.com.au and site.com.au

**Website with Facebook Login**: http://mysite.com.au

**App Type**: Web

**Sandbox mode**: Disabled

**Stream post URL security**: Disabled

**Remove offline access permission**: Disabled

**Forces use of login secret for auth.login**: Enabled

**September, October, August 2012 Breaking Changes**: Disabled

Answer (score 0):

It turns out for whatever reason the fb-button tags were generating bad links or something wasn't linking up properly. In the end I did this which works perfectly.

```
<a onclick="loginfb(); return false;" class="flogin"></a>
<script>

    function loginfb()
    {
     FB.login(function(response) 
     {
       if (response.authResponse) 
       {
            goLogIn();
       }
     });        
    }
    function goLogIn(){
        window.location = "/events/facebook/check";
    }



</script>
```